# how can i figure out what my kivy app heigth and width should be for a given device?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on an android app using kivy and buildozer. I have a google pixel xl device for testing. I have the tech specs for this model from [Device Metrics](https://material.io/devices/).
how do I determine from the given specs what the height and width of my app should be?

I currently use windows to write and run my code, and kivy vm for packaging into android apk. I know that kivy sizes your app automatically, but I want to sort of simulate the size of my device screen when running my code on windows, so that I don't have to build an apk every time I want to test how it would look on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy has a [module for this](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.screen.html), which will set the size of the app Window to emulate a specific device.

Comment: I did not know this existed, thanks. I looked into it and there is a list of supported devices listed, yet the pixel and pixel xl are not on the list. would still like to know how I can achieve the same effect without the use of this module. beginner trying to learn.

Comment: You can specify any set of sizes you like to emulate other devices. And to see how it works, you can [read the code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/modules/screen.py).

Comment: so all I have to do is specify the settings for my particular device in the screen.py file and run the command for that added device?

Comment: i followed your link and i found the following model for example: 'phone_htc_one_m9': ('HTC One M9', 1920, 1080, 432, 3.0),
now, when i go https://material.io/devices/ and look at the matrics for the same device i don't see the number 432 anywhere, i find the 1920, 1080, and 3.0, but i don't see the 432 for the dpi. how can i figure out what the dpi for any given device(not listed in the screen.py) so i can add it to screen.py?

Comment: I found the device dpi by going into the device settings>developer options.